# Unity: pass parameters to custom lifetime constructor, in xml configuration file

Tags: c#, configuration, inversion-of-control, unity-container, lifetime

I wrote my CustomLifetimeManager like this:

```
public class CustomLifetimeManager <T> : LifetimeManager
{
    private readonly string _arg;

    public CustomLifetimeManager(string arg)
    {
      _arg = arg;
    }
}
```

Now, it works easy configuring the container programmatically, but how add it in configuration file like the following?

```
<type type="myTime"
      mapTo="myImpl">
      <lifetime type="CustomLifetimeManager"/>
</type>
```

Comment: Do you want to read the config? If you do, add keys with values and read them like so:
string configValue = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.type["keyName"];

Comment: No, i want just call: unityConfigurationSection.Containers[0].Configure(Container)
to get my container configured.

I would like to configure the lifetime manager in the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a second class: A TypeConverter. This class is responsible for taking a string and turning it into whatever type you want. Once you implement it, you can then do something like this in your config file:

```
<register type="MyType" mapTo"MyImpl">
  <lifetime typeConverter="CustomLifetimeManagerConverter" value="arg" />
</register>
```

and from there it should just work (assuming the config can find the type converter like any other type).